# Adding a JOIN between two tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

Here is the classes I have:

```
Model Organization
has_many Students

Model Student
has_many Classes
belongs_to Organization

Model Class
a field named : price
belongs_to Student
scope :top_expensive_classes, joins(:students).order('price DESC')
```

**Now I want to list the top 10 expensive classes**

At least the first problem I have is that in the `params` I have the `organization_id` to filter based on that But I write my controller like this which does NOT work because it thinks it should find organization_id in the `Class` model but it is in the `Student` model.

```
@results = Class.top_expensive_classes.where(organization_id: params[:id]).limit(RESULT_SET_COUNT)
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to fix this? I think I should introduce a new join somewhere? but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Why doesn't `Class` have any associations defined? Can you post the `Program` model? What exactly is your query supposed to get? Most expensive classes for all students connected to a specific organization?

Comment: @Jesper : Yes sorry, I updated the association, basically they are hanging off of each other in the hierarchy.  And yes you got it :"Most expensive classes for all students connected to a specific organization "  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your scope: `joins:(:programs)` should be `joins(:programs)`

To fetch based on the organization id in Student you may be able to do this:

```
@results = Class.top_expensive_classes
  .joins(student: :organization)
  .where(organization: {id: params[:id]})
```

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with correct names and syntax like this: joins(:students).order('price DESC')
BUT  still it has the same problem. It thinks it should look for organization_id on the Class table.